# PHP dom - converting russian language to entity

Tags: php, dom

I am using PHP dom to remove some classes and id,
But this is also converting my Russian language to entity (all other language except English are converted to entity).

Like:

```
контекстное = ÐºÐ¾Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑÑ‚
```

when I see source code then I see this:

```
&ETH;&ordm;&ETH;&frac34;&ETH;&frac12;&Ntilde;
```

How to stop dom to convert my language to entity.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251) comment on php.net.

Quoting:

```
You can also load HTML as UTF-8 using this simple hack:

<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);

// dirty fix
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item)
    if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
        $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper

?>
```